# VSCode Snippet trigger with text before?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I want to create a snippet in VSCode that display the PHP arrow.
When I press the key "²" then TAB I want the PHP arrow "->".

Here is my snippet code

```
"PHP arrow": {
    "prefix": "²",
    "body": "->$0",
    "description": "PHP Arrow ->"
},
```

It works fine when there is nothing around the "²" char but when I write some code like

```php
$this²
```

the snippet is not triggered

What can I do ?

Thank you and have a nice day :)

PS: The **²** char is **oem_7** in VSCode

Comment: What keystrokes are you using to insert the superscript 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what keystrokes you are using to insert the superscript ².  But if you are trying to use it as a snippet at the end of a word try making a keybinding instead.

**VSCode has no way of knowing whether that ² is intended to be part of a word or not.**

Try this in your **keybindings.json** - not in a snippet file:

```
{
  "key": "2",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "resourceExtname == .php",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "->$0"
  }
}
```

Typing `$this2` yields `$this->`:

[image: php snippet demo]

Obviously you will have to replace the `2` key above with whatever you want to use.  Now you can use the snippet as part of a word or at the end of a word without any necessary word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this issue is that VS Code does not know that `²` should be treated as its own "word". This is easier to understand if you consider a snippet that uses a letter prefix, such as `x`:

```
"PHP arrow": {
    "prefix": "x",
    "body": "->$0",
    "description": "PHP Arrow ->"
}
```

This snippet would not be triggered if you type out `ax|` because `x` is part of the word `ax`, and the snippet prefix of `x` does not match the word `ax`.

In your example of `$this²|`, the word used to check the prefix is `this²` which the snippet's prefix does not match.

---

@Mark is probably correct to suggest that you come up with an alternative workflow. Short of writing an extension, I don't think you can make your current approach work smoothly

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have a nice day !