# remap keys vscode to emit different values

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my previous setup, I was somehow able to remap `²`-key (completely useless) into emitting `->` (=aka pointer access in C), but I can't find how I did it, neither I can find action in the documentation how to "emit" value upon pressing a key.

How should I do that?

Comment: see the key binding doc and use the command `type` with argument `"=>"` (see example), to find key code for a particular key use `Record Keys` in Keyboard Shortcuts window

Comment: Seehttps://stackoverflow.com/a/56031727/836330 for similar.  How are you emitting the superscript 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In keybindings.json

```
{
    // "key": "²",
    "key": "alt+2",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    // "when": "resourceExtname == .c",   // if you want this
    "args": {
      "snippet": "->$0"
    }
  },
```

I'm not sure how you are inserting the superscript `²` which could change the answer, but this example works.