# Define when VS Code shows snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

Is there any setting where I can define when (not) to show suggestions? Currently I am setting up VS Code for writing LaTeX and I am creating a lot of user snippets. But when I create a snippet whichs prefix starts with a non-letter character, the suggestions menu isn't coming up. For example I have the following snippet:

```
"rightarrow":{
    "prefix": ["->", "rarrow"],
    "body": "\\rightarrow"
},
```

but the suggestions menu is not showing up when typing "->". I have to press `Ctrl`+`Space` manually to bring up the menu or insert the snippet with `Ctrl`+`P`>"Insert Snippet", which makes it hard to write fast:

You can see it on this gif: [Suggestion menu not showing up despite inserting the prefix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYoSH.gif)

When I type the text, the suggestion menu pops up and I can hit enter to insert the snippet, but when i type "->" there is no menu that comes up, even though I typed the prefix.

I see that it makes sense that per default it is not showing, but is there a way to show suggestions then too? VS Code only shows it when the prefix starts with a letter, which limits me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the minimal char count before the suggestion is shown is 3 characters

Comment: I have tried to use "-->" as well. It doesn't help. I can add as many hypens as I want but it never shows up.

Comment: if you use an `a-z`+ prefix when does it show the snippet, so if you want rightarrow try a prefix, `rarrow`, `prefix` can be an array

Comment: I could use "rarrow" as prefix and it would show up after typing two letters, but that would be less intuitiv to me. I was hoping I could use "->". It's also isn't the only thing I want to add using a special-sign-prefix. It would be usefull for a lot of math related snippets too. I know that the prefix can be an array but that doesn't help when the snippet isn't showing :D

Comment: You have some other issue.  I copied your code and I get the snippet suggestion with just the opening `-`.  Are you using this within a string?

Comment: What? Really? No I am not using it within a string or something. Every other snippet that starts with a letter works just fine, but not these. I really can't explain why it's working for you. I have also added it to snippet-files for other file types and it's the same there for me. Have you changed any VS Code settings regarding this? Or can you post your settings.json? I have also tried this in another fresh installation in a vm (with pretty much no settings changed) and it's the same there.

Comment: @Mark I just tried and for me it suggests also on the `-` sign

Comment: Then you people must have changed something. I even tried on the plain https://vscode.dev/ website which should be a plain installation and it also doesn't work there. Can you tell what you changed that might cause that behavior?

Comment: I also installed the VS Code Insiders version now but it still isn't working as you explained. Can you tell if you changed something @Mark and @rioV8?

Comment: I do have `Editor: Snippet Suggestions` set to `top`.  And the `editor.quicksuggestions` are all set to `true` (comments/other/strings).  And `editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions` false.

Comment: @Mark hm, I also have the same settings but it's still not working. But thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: You might try the extension Bisect command to see if one of your extensions is conflicting with the snippet.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56031727/836330 - that might be helpful.

Comment: @Mark I did use Bisect (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P` and searching Bisect) but after the process it says that no extension was found and the problem is: "Code". The other link you posted unfortunately didn't help since I still need my hyphen for other things and can't remap it.

Comment: @Mark could you perhaps post your settings.json file at a https://justpaste.it/ page (or something else) as well a list of extensions you use? (If it's not too much effort). I would really love if I could get this to work but I can't get it done. I have searched for hours by now but I can't find the right setting/extension even on fresh installations.

Comment: Please @Mark ... it would really help me a lot.

Comment: Edit your question to show a gif of how you are actually attempting to use that snippet - that could be helpful.

Comment: @Mark I can't embedd images yet, stackoverflow just creates a link to some imgur page. If you click the link in the question you will see the gif now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found this issue which looks to be right on:

[Snippet doesn't get triggered for certain tokens](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/124751):

> Ok. Thanks for clarifying. Quick suggestion is working on at the end
> of "words". What a word is can be re-defined by extensions, e.g latex
> say => is valid word.

[I tested it in a non-latex file where your snippet works fine without manually bringing up intellisense, that was dumb of me ;>}.]

The problem is the latex language must not use the `- >` characters as word separators, so when you type those characters vscode has chosen to not pop up suggestions because it thinks you may be within a word and doesn't want to constantly pop up suggestions when it doesn't know you are within a word.

By the way, apparently latex snippets provided by an extension are not treated this same way and the suggestions can pop up automatically.

I don't think there is any work-around except to make your own latex snippet extension and see if it works how you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now at least I understand why it's not working :D
Maybe one day I will write an extension, but I have to learn how do do so first. But thanks a lot for taking time and helping me Mark! :)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else has this problem: Another way of solving this somewhat is to assign the command "insertSnippet" to a custom key binding (I used alt+space). This always inserts the snippet if the entire prefix is typed, even if no suggestion is showing up (also when in snippet mode).